# Все значения ассоциативного массива в нижний регистр

Tags: php

Может быть кто-то уже писал такую функцию или есть стандартная (не смог найти).

Нужно все значения пришедшего массива полностью загнать в нижний регистр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array_map("strtolower", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` и `strtolower` вам помогут